# How to play this on violin?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, violin

[image: Sheet Music]

I'm not able to find clear answers to this on the internet. There are multiple slur marks on the notes. One slur for the first 7 notes. But another marking says to slur the first 14 notes. And yet another marking says to slur the first 21 notes. How do I play this on the violin?

This is an excerpt from 'Scales for Advanced Violinists' by Barbara Barber.

Comment: Hi.  In all posts, please provide the name of the piece, or the name of the exercise book, etc. so we can discover what instructions you may have overlooked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like an exercise, since it is numbered "3" and it's just a G major scale.

You practice it three different ways, with the three different bowings.

Comment: I'm not convinced, but  you might be right if we can find the source.

Comment: I may have that exercise book, it looks familiar. This is a common practice in many of the scale books I have; it indicates to change to multiple notes per bow as you practice the scale.